# how to replace a string inside perl regex

Tags: regex, perl, inline

Is there a way to replace characters from inside the regex?

like so:

```
find x | xargs perl -pi -e 's/(as dasd asd)/replace(" ","",$1)/'
```

**From OP's comment**

```
code find x | xargs perl -pi -e 's/work_search=1\/ttype=2\/tag=(.*?)">(.*?)<\/a>/work\/\L$1\E\" rel=\"follow\">$2<\/a>/g'
```

in this case i want $1's spaces be replaced with _

Answer (score 2):

You can use a nested substitution:

```
$ echo 'foo bar baz' | perl -wpE's/(\w+ \w+ \w+)/ $1 =~ s# ##gr /e'
foobarbaz
```

Note that the `/r` modifier requires perl v5.14. For earlier versions, use:

```
$ echo 'foo bar baz' | perl -wpE's/(\w+ \w+ \w+)/my $x=$1; $x=~s# ##g; $x/e'
foobarbaz
```

Note also that you need to use a different delimiter for the inner substitution. I used `#`, as you can see.

Comment: This answer could be improved by adding spaces around the "=~"

Comment: @hochgurgler Perhaps readability could be improved, but I detest one-liners that are so long that they trigger the scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you want to remove the spaces. Is it correct?

You can do:

```
s/(as) (dasd) (asd)/$1$2$3/
```

Comment: correct, but the "(as dads asd)" is just a part of the regex - sorry for confusion, but i didn't post the entire regex:
`code` find x | xargs perl -pi -e 's/work_search=1\/ttype=2\/tag=(.*?)">(.*?)<\/a>/work\/\L$1\E\" rel=\"follow\">$2<\/a>/g'

in this case i want $1's spaces be replaced with _

Comment: <a href="/work_search=1/ttype=2/tag=S & A Homes">S & A Homes</a>
should become
<a href="/work/s_&_a_homes">S & A Homes</a>

Comment: @user845435: Please edit you question instead of add comment with code.